# Generating primes up to n using sifting, but object not subscriptable error when I iterate over certain numbers?

Tags: python, primes

I am trying to **generate primes up to some integer n**. Here is my code, (I use **sifting** to eliminate multiples of visited primes):

```
def generate_primes(n):
    if n < 2:
        return []
    size = (n - 3) // 2 + 1
    primes = [2]
    is_prime = [True] * size

    for i in range(size):
        if is_prime[i]:
            p = i * 2 + 3
            primes.append(p)

            #sifting out primes
            for j in range(2 * i ** 2 + 6 * i + 3, size, p):
                is_prime = False
    return primes

print(generate_primes(100))
```

However, I am getting an error for the `if is_prime[I] statement`, `TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable`. I don't see why this is the case, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You're setting `is_prime` to `False`,causing it to become a boolean. I think you want to do `is_prime[j] = false`, causing only that element to become `False`

Comment: Ahh yes okay thanks, I see it now

Answer (score 0):

Cmon, you reassigned `is_prime = [True] * size` list variable to `bool`: `is_prime = False`. And this is a bad way of generating primes.